# physical address to DIMM

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

From within the Linux kernel, what would be the best way to map a physical address to a DIMM? (find out which DIMM contains a given physical address)

Also how would a DIMM be referenced inside the kernel (channel number and DIMM number?)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108035/is-it-possible-to-find-the-physical-address-range-of-a-dimm